# Spring Boot 2.6.12 compatibility with Spring Cloud (Config) 2021.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to update my project Spring Boot version from 2.4.13 to 2.6.12

We were using Spring Cloud 2020.0.0-M6 and I also wanted to bump the version to 2021.0.4

Now my application won't load its remote configuration even though I can see in the logs that it finds the service and the configuration!!

[image]

In the above picture you can see my app does find the config-service once deployed to our Development environment.

[image]

And after that, it throws me an error because it's trying to use its local configuration where I'm using Environment Variables set from my IDE, using the following syntax ${var}, to replace the value depending on the Run/Debug Configuration.

In the meantime, I'm trying to use Spring Boot 2.6.11 with Spring Cloud 2021.0.4. If I can't get it to work I will have to downgrade it to the last working version until I find the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: See the breaking changes in the release notes https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes-1 about `spring.config.import` or `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks I'll try adding the dependency even though I already tried it before posting. What I didn't know was the possibility to set Spring Clouds version as a property like spring-cloud.version = 2021.1. Right now I set the version in my pom.xml using dependencyManagement.